# How to install Socialite 2.0 on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, sdk

I'm trying to install socialite 2.0 on laravel 5.2 via composer but it gives me an error:

> The requested package laravel/socialite ^3.0 exists as laravel/socialite[v2.0.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.

```
- laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- laravel/socialite v3.0.3 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- illuminate/http v5.4.9 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/http v5.4.13 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/http v5.4.0 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for laravel/socialite ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
```

socialite 3.0 requires laravel 5.4 which i can't install because my php version is 5.5, any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update `composer.json` to `"laravel/socialite": "2.0.20"`, use the exact version. Found it in [here](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases).

**Update**

Use `~` to get latest version of 2.*. Following means >= 2.0 and < 3.0.0

`"laravel/socialite": "~2.0"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command

```
composer require laravel/socialite ~2.0.0
```